# Getting 'System Model' Remotly

Tags: batch-file

I want to make a script that tells me what is the "SYSTEM MODEL" of remotes computers in my network (not domain) with credensials of remote local acount (WORKGROUP\SCRIPTOS).
i know how to make FOR loop to jump from one WS to another but i don't know the syntax to get the information.
the closest thing that I can get is the System BIOS Version by this scrpit that I made and it's working:

```
@echo off
title  check pos types
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

:: day sets ::
set mm=%date:~-10,2%
set dd=%date:~-7,2%
set yy=%date:~-4%
set TODAY=%dd%-%mm%-%yy%



set CompType=POS
set Computerslist=posIP.txt
set output=%TODAY%_%CompType%_Type.txt


echo Station    Computer Type   IP  Bion Version>%output%
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%A in (%Computerslist%) do (   
    set stationNum=%%A
    set CompIP=%%B
    echo Checking BIOS %CompType% In Station Number !stationNum!, Please wait...
    net use \\!CompIP! /USER:WORKGROUP\USER PASSWORDS       
    srvinfo -nf-ns \\!CompIP! >%temp%\srvinfo.txt
    for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('findstr /c:"System BIOS Version:" %temp%\srvinfo.txt') do set BiosVersion=%%f
    echo !stationNum!   !CompType!  !CompIP!    !BiosVersion!>>%output%

    del /q %temp%\srvinfo.txt
    )
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

```
wmic /node:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx /user:uuuu /password:pppp csproduct get name
```

Just ask the OS. But to use it, an administrator account is needed.

Comment: that's nice, but I think I can't get WMIC from my remote computers (The RPC server is unavailable).